# rm: cannot remove '<Directory name>': Device or resource busy

Tags: directory, rm, devices, delete

I know there can be a lot of duplicates. I have gone through almost all of them (like lsof, fuser, etc) and I could not get it resolved.

> rm: cannot remove 'temp_p/sys': Device or resource busy

This is the error I receive while trying to delete a folder from a bash script.
The command I use is:

```
test -f "$TEMP_DIR" && sudo rm -rf "$TEMP_DIR"
```

I tried to do rm -rf from the shell, and it shows the same output. 
Output of lsof is:

```
lsof +D <directory name>
```

> lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/76585/gvfs
>         Output information may be incomplete.
>   lsof: WARNING: can't stat() vfat file system /media/kostef1/9016-4EF8
>         Output information may be incomplete.

Fuser also does not show anything.
If I list all hidden files, it still hoes not show anything starting with dot.

Comment: The filesystem driver has probably crashed, either that or it hadn't even noticed it should've crashed. I would suggest rebooting the computer.

Comment: What filesystem is the file on? Is it a regular file?

Comment: @Gilles It is ext4, and on Ubuntu 16.04 (running on a NUC)

Answer (score 1):

It suggests `temp_p/sys` has a filesystem mounted on it, you'd need to unmount it first:

```
umount -- "$TEMP_DIR/sys"
rm -rf -- "$TEMP_DIR"
```

Or:

```
if mountpoint -q -- "$TEMP_DIR/sys"; then
  umount -- "$TEMP_DIR/sys" || exit
fi
rm -rf -- "$TEMP_DIR"
```

To check whether it is a mount point first, and abort if it can't be unmounted.

BTW, your `rm -rf` will have cleaned the contents of the filesystem mounted there, which the above avoids.

To empty `$TEMP_DIR`, leaving alone file on separate file systems, you can use `find`:

```
find "$TEMP_DIR" -xdev -depth -delete
```

(`-delete` implies `-depth`, but it's good practice to still include it as a reminder).

Also note that *`test -f "$TEMP_DIR"`* is to test whether `$TEMP_DIR` is a *regular* file (after symlink resolution), it would return false for any other type of file including directories. Maybe you meant `test -d` instead. Also note that with `-f`, `rm` wouldn't complain if asked to remove a file that is already gone, so it's fine to invoke it on something that may not exist.